# Find/Do Loop - Excel 2010

Tags: vba, excel-2010

I would like to use the find/do function to find the word Spike within range J28:J115.  When it is found, two values are obtained and pasted into another worksheet.  I want it to look for the word, place the values, and then look for the word again until all values have been placed.

Here is my code so far.

```
' Find Spike Sample Name, paste in QAQC file'

    Windows("a").Activate
    Range("J28:J115").Select
    Selection.Find(What:="spike", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
    LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, -8).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("b").Activate
    Sheets("Spike").Select
    Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False

'Copy Sample Value, paste in QAQC file'
    Windows("Macro 20170113 NH3 BP Jan13 Stan Jan9 with smp blk JZ.xlsx").Activate
    Range("J28:J115").Select
    Selection.Find(What:="spike", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
    LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("Macro Ammonia QA-QC Chart 20161104.xlsx").Activate
    Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
    Selection.NumberFormat = "0.0"
    ActiveCell = ActiveCell * 100
```

Answer (score 1):

The following achieves the loop for the first part of your code. I have no clue what you are trying to do next. Don't forget to set the source sheet's name where indicated.

```
Dim r As Range, first As Range, x As Range
Set r = Sheets("source").Range("J28:J115") ' <-- set the name to your source sheet
Set first = r.Find("spike", r(1, 1), xlValues, xlWhole, xlByRows, xlNext, False, False)
If Not first Is Nothing Then
    Set x = first
    Do
        Sheets("Spike").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = x.offset(, -8).Value

        Set x = r.FindNext(x) ' , xlValues, xlWhole, xlByRows, xlNext)
    Loop Until x.Address = first.Address
End If
```